# How do I automate data extract from Hive to Windows desktop?

Tags: python, hive

I have to login to bastion Linux host then run kinit and `beeline` using pbrun, then sftp csv file to Windows.

Query sample:

"SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE id > 100"

Is there a Python script or tool to automate this?

Comment: _"I have to login to bastion"_ > is it a Security requirement, or is it just that nobody thought to connect to Hive from Windows (with e.g. DBeaver, DBVisualizer, etc.) using the Java `kinit` to create the required Kerberos ticket?

Comment: i have to pbrun using functional account and that is set up only on Linux. keytab  has entries set for given fqdn and user and I have no access to kadmin

Comment: This sounds silly. There's an impedance mismatch between Big Data -- where the point is to _use_ the data -- and these "security" solutions from the 90's _(PowerBroker, Centrify, CyberArk etc)_ who were designed to _restrict_ access to servers admin tools. The whole Hadoop stack uses Kerberos authentication, which allows for end-to-end audit trails, including for data access _(think GDPR audits about proper usage of personal information)_.  Using a service account breaks that feature.

Comment: And the fact that their "so precious" data, "so strongly protected", will end up on your PC with no way to track its usage... quite defeats the purpose of their obsolete security standards & mindset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post my findings.
The most difficult part was figuring out expect+pbrun.
Because there are 2 interactive questions I had to pause for a sec after first question.

My `expect` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 300
set usr [lindex $argv 0];
set pwd [lindex $argv 1];
set query_file [lindex $argv 2];
spawn -noecho pbrun $usr &
expect -re "Password:"
send "$pwd\r"

sleep 1
expect "Enter reason for this privilege access:"
send "test\r"

send "kinit -k -t /opt/Cloudera/keytabs/`whoami`.`hostname -s`.keytab `whoami`/`hostname -f`@YOUR_FQDN_NAME.NET;ssl=true\r"
send "beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://bigdataplatform-your_dev.net:10000/;principal=hive/bigdataplatform-your_dev.net@YOUR_FQDN_NAME.NET;ssl=true' --outputformat=csv2 --verbose=false  --fastConnect=true   --silent=true -f $query_file;\r"

expect "*]$\ " {send "exit\r"}
expect eof
```

Query:

```
select * from gfocnnsg_work.pytest LIMIT  1000000;
```

The rest is Python and paramiko. 
I create Transport object, execute expect script, and save standard output on Windows OS.

Data access path:

```
Windows desktop->
               SSH->
                  Linux login->
                      pbrun service login-> 
                                          kinit 
                                          beeline-> 
                                                  SQL-> 
                                                      save echo on Windows
```

Here's a Python script with details: [hivehoney](https://github.com/hive-scripts/hivehoney)

Answer (score 0):

You could put yours query to file, for example hive_script.sql
and run his from terminal

```
hive -f hive_script.sql
```